# How can I resize images

Tags: jquery, image

I have PHP pagination with jQuery using table, I have images in first column of each row, and there is jQuery ui slider that allow me to resize images but is only work resize n first row, how can I resize all images in FIRST COLUMN of all images at at the same time!

Please see demo at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonred/rgu5E/)

```
var orginalWidth = $("#image").width();

$("#infoSlider").text(orginalWidth + ', 100%');

$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    step: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var fraction = (1 + ui.value / 100),
            newWidth = orginalWidth * fraction;

        $("#infoSlider").text(newWidth + ', ' + Math.floor(fraction * 100) + '%');

        $("#image").width(newWidth);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID must be unqiue, uses classes instead:

```
<img class="image" src="http://practicalaction.org/images/sea-of-ducks-300.jpg" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rgu5E/1/)**

```
var orginalWidth = $(".image").width();
$("#infoSlider").text(orginalWidth + ', 100%');
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    step: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var fraction = (1 + ui.value / 100),
            newWidth = orginalWidth * fraction;

        $("#infoSlider").text(newWidth + ', ' + Math.floor(fraction * 100) + '%');

        $(".image").width(newWidth);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, yes your right, id must be unique, again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `id` for all of your images. That's not good.

Try identifying them using a *class* instead, e.g.

```
<img ... class="resizable-image" ... />
```

and then use the `.resizable-image` instead of `#image` selector in jQuery.